# How to connect a Java container with a MySQL container?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, jdbc, jooq

I am reading the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/) and stuck at the following step
[image]

The app used in the document supports env variables like `MYSQL_HOST` and `MYSQL_USER` and so on, but my program is Java and doesn't support them.
Instead, I use the following connection string in the java code to connect to the DB:

```
return new DefaultConfiguration().set(DriverManager.getConnection(
                                            "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?serverTimezone=UTC",
                                            "root",
                                            "111111"))
                                 .set(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
```

So how should I alter the connection string? Because now the connection fails as shown below

```
Jul 05, 2021 12:31:35 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger error

SEVERE: Error in file: /app/build/tmp/generateJooq/config.xml. Error : Communications link failure


The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

For the `host`, should I change it to `localhost`? I ran `select user();` in mysql command line and got the following result

```
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```

Does that mean the host is `localhost`?

However, when I ran `show variables;` the value of `hostname` is `1f1632505b1f`, so why are there two host names?

For port, I inspected the MySQL image and it exposes `3306`, so I think this part I don't need to change, is that correct?

For the DB name, I created a DB named `test` so I think this part should be fine. The same for username and password.

Inspect the MySQL container:
[image]

`my.cnf` file specifies `bind-address=0.0.0.0`:
[image]

Logs of the mysql container:
[image]

Comment: A good practice would be to construct the connection string from the [environment variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) you reference, rather than hard-coding something in the application.  `localhost` in Docker generally means "this container"; documentation like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes how to make connections between containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the suggestion. You are right, and I have changed to using env variables.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to configure your MySQL server to listen on all addresses, e.g. by editing this file inside of your docker container

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And specifying

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

See also https://serverfault.com/q/139323

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work for me. Please take a look at the update, where I added the `my.cnf` file and logs. The same error still shows up. (I am using `jdbc:mysql://amazing_herschel:3306/test?serverTimezone=UTC` as connection string, where `amazing_herschel` is the name of the mysql container. Since they are in the same docker network, I guess it should work, is that correct?) Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the mysql container doesn't need to expose a port, since the java container accesses it inside the docker network, is that correct?

Comment: have you tried connecting to `localhost` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I forgot to run migration first...

In my `Dockerfile`, I should have run `./gradlew flywayMigrate` then `./gradlew runApp` (which is a task of type `JavaExec`), but I forgot the former, hence the error.

It is counter-intuitive that the error only mentions that the DB connection failed, not anything about migration..

Thanks for all the help!